# calculate the distance of data on specific column using python language

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, distance

i have data.txt, i want calculate this data with python.

`id,target,ordinal1,ordinal2,ordinal3,nominal1,nominal2,ordinal4,ordinal5,ordinal6
1,T,high,high,high,teacher,nokia,medium,3,low
2,T,high,medium,high,teacher,nokia,medium,3,low
3,F,high,medium,high,farmer,samsung,medium,3,low
4,T,high,medium,high,lawyer,sony,low,1,low
5,F,high,medium,high,doctor,lenovo,low,1,low
6,T,high,high,high,police,iphone,low,1,low
7,F,high,low,high,doctor,samsung,medium,2,low
8,T,high,low,high,farmer,sony,low,2,low
9,F,high,medium,medium,lawyer,lenovo,medium,2,low
10,T,medium,high,low,employee,nokia,low,1,low`

from this data, i want calculate d(i,j) = (s-t)/s. where s is total number of nominal (from this data s = 2), t is attributes for i & j are in same state (for ex: i is row 1 and j is row 2, so t=2). but i only want calculate data with column nominal1 and nominal2.

for t can be viewed as the:

```
    nominal1    nominal2
i      a           b
j      c           d


if a==c && b==d
    t=2
if a==c || b==d
    t=1
else 0
```

I have tried to encodes a bit, but I am still confused how to make the column just nominal1 and nominal2 that in reading and how to encode that s = 2 and t will have value as described above. can someone tell me what should I do?

This bit of code that I do

```
def distance(data,target_attr):
    val_freq = {}
    data_distance = 0.0

    # Calculate the frequency of each of the values in the target attr
    for record in data:
        if (val_freq.has_key(record[target_attr])):
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] += 1.0
        else:
            val_freq[record[target_attr]] = 1.0

    for i in val_freq.values():


    return (s-t)/s
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would implement:

```
def distance(list1, list2):
    s = len(list1)
    t = sum(map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1, list2))

    # note: float() is important here, or you would nearly always get zero!
    return float(s-t)/s
```

Explanation of `sum(map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1 list2))`:

```
>>> list1 = [1,True,"high",42,"low"]
>>> list2 = [1,False,"low",42,"low"]
>>> map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1, list2)
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> sum(map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1, list2))
3
```

This method calculates the distance for two tuples concerning *all* attributes as norminals. If you want to have less attributes, you can use:

```
distance(list1[3:5], list2[3:5]) # take just list[3] and list[4] in consideration
```

Short note: Here is an error:

```
if a==c && b==d
    t=2
if a==c || b==d
    t=1
else 0
```

You mean:

```
if a==c && b==d
    t=2
elif a==c || b==d
    t=1
else 0
```

`elif` is important here, because otherwise `t == 1` also for `a==c && b==d`.

Comment: if I use this t = sum(map(lambda x,y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1 list2)). value for t is 1 or 0. so if result for data will value t = 2, The code can not be used. am i right ?

Comment: Don't forget the sum in the end!

Comment: see the last edit of my question (note: I made a typo and forgot a comma between ``list1`` and ``list2`` – I corrected it now)

Comment: the data that I used to have 1000 rows. so if I use the function for how to include it. is like this:for i in range​​(list1):
t = sum (map (lambda x, y: 1 if x == y else 0, list1[i], list2[i]))

Comment: nope, your code will also not work... ``map`` wants to have iterables for its second and third argument... Have you understood, how my posted code functions?

Comment: yes, i understand with your code functions. but I'm still confused, if there is has repetition of data, how do I put it.